# stuck in the for c# loop!

Tags: c#, xml, transliteration

i have two xml files which have devanagri to itrans mapping, these files are dev.xml
and gujarati.xml. The xml file contents are as follows:

for guj.xml it is:

```
<mapping>
  <character>અ</character>
  <itrans>a</itrans>
</mapping>
```

and for dev.xml it is

```
<mapping>
    <character>अ</character>
    <itrans>a</itrans>
</mapping>
```

I have a global.asax file which has the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;

namespace finAL
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sbyte[,] d = new sbyte[100, 100];
            sbyte[,] g = new sbyte[100, 100];
            int count = 0;
            int j = 0;

            XmlDocument docA = new XmlDocument();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("dev.xml");
            docA.Load(sr);

            XmlDocument docB = new XmlDocument();
            StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader("guj.xml");
            docB.Load(sr1);

            XmlNodeList elemlist1 = root.GetElementsByTagName("mapping");
            XmlNodeList elemlist2 = root.GetElementsByTagName("mapping");
            XmlNodeList X;

            for (int i = 0; i < elemlist1.Count; i++)
            {
                X = elemlist1[i].GetElementsByTagName("itrans");
                d[i][0] = X[0].firstchild.data;


                X = elemlist1[i].GetElementsByTagName("character");
                d[i][1] = X[0].firstchild.data;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < elemlist2.Count; i++)
            {
                X = elemlist1[i].GetElementsByTagName("itrans");
                g[i][0] = X[0].firstchild.data;

                X = elemlist1[i].GetElementsByTagName("character");
                g[i][1] = X[0].firstchild.data;
            }

            Session("dtable") = d;
            Session("gtable") = g;
        }
    }
}
```

The code here reads from the both the xml files and stores the characters in a two dimensional array. This array isfurther stored in a session variable so that I can access it in default.aspx

The default.aspx file contains the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml;

namespace finAL
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sbyte[,] TableD = new sbyte[100, 100];
            sbyte[,] TableG = new sbyte[100, 100];
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml("<div>" & Request.Form("inTransContent")   & "</div>");
            XmlNodeList nodeList;
            nodeList = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//text()");
            TableD = Session("dtable");
            TableG = Session("gtable");
            String str=tmpNode.data;
            str.ToCharArray();
            foreach (XmlText tmpNode in nodeList)
            {

            }
            Response.Write(doc.DocumentElement.InnerXml);
        }
    }
}
```

here the intranscontent contains the webpage with the div element.
so I select the textnodes from them. In this code I am accessing the session variable which were in the global.asax the nodes are converted to strings and then to chararray so that I can replace the characters of devanagri to gujarati.

In the for loop I need to check for every devanagri character an equivalent gujarati character keeping in mind all the transliteration rules.the transliteration rules are like if the previous character is vowel then it should output vowel only. If anyone could help me with this for loop I will be thankful to them. Thanks! any queries plz free to post.

Comment: First of all you should consider refactoring your code. Rename your variables to more meaningful names. It'll help to find errors and you will be able to understand your code even in a few months.

Comment: `if the previous character is vowel then it should output vowel only` - this sounds strange, could you describe it any other way?

Comment: काम is in hindi, so in itrans it is kaam, so in hindi क is represented as  k and a is represented as अ but when your checking the next character it is again the letter a,so once you check that letter it has to interpret it as aa which maps to आ..if you understand hindi you would get it easily,there are some transliteration rules,the problem is that it has to check for the future characters whether it is a vowel or consonant!! if it is a vowel it has to use some different transliteration rule and if it is a consonant it has to use something else.

Comment: That sounds complex. Are you sure it can be done? A Dictionary<string,string> instead of Dictionary<char,char> might be a start and then matching and transliterating the longest (like aa before a) first could be a start.

Comment: Why are TableD and TableG sbyte[100,100] when you only seems to use, at most, [100,2]?

Comment: hey i got it!! i used the linq thing!! i could finally transliterate dev to guj!! but a new problem has emerged the replacing characters procedure is taking time!! i mean when i say transliterate it takes time to search the equivalent characters and replace it!! if anyone could tell me how can i do it faster!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `itrans` really are a unique identifier, which I doubt, between Devanagri and Gujarati characters then I would recommend creating a `Dictionary<char,char>` instead of an array.

```
var gujarati = "<mappings><mapping><character>અ</character><itrans>a</itrans></mapping><mapping><character>ત</character><itrans>i</itrans></mapping></mappings>";
var devanagri = "<mappings><mapping><character>अ</character><itrans>a</itrans></mapping><mapping><character>र</character><itrans>i</itrans></mapping></mappings>";

var gujDict = XDocument.Parse(gujarati).
                Descendants("mapping").
                ToDictionary(ele => ele.Element("itrans").Value[0], ele => ele.Element("character").Value[0]);
var devDict = XDocument.Parse(devanagri).
                Descendants("mapping").
                ToDictionary(ele => ele.Element("itrans").Value[0], ele => ele.Element("character").Value[0]);

var devToGuj = new Dictionary<char, char>();

foreach (var c in devDict) 
{
    char dev;
    if (gujDict.TryGetValue(c.Key, out dev))
        devToGuj.Add(c.Value, dev);
}
```

Then you just `devToGuj['અ']` to get the corresponding character. To replace the characters in a string you could do something like this.

```
var devText = "अ quरck test.";
var gujText = String.Join("", 
                    devText.ToArray().
                    Select(c => devToGuj.ContainsKey(c) ? devToGuj[c] : c)
                    );
```

> => "અ quતck test."

Comment: i dont want to use linq!! i want to access xml files where it will opened and read using streamreader and then store it in an two dimensional array which will be stored in a session object.

Comment: Don't you want to use LINQ or can't you use it because your still in .NET 2.0 land? What's your problem with LINQ?

Comment: Also the lookups I proposed has nothing to do with LINQ but are just a simple Dictionary lookup. If performance is very important you should benchmark different ways of storing them since for small amounts of items in a collection a List<T> or array is actually faster than a Dictionary even though a Dictionary is pretty close to O(1).